# Why is my canvas blank except for in a corner?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm in the process of learning JavaScript by playing with the canvas, I've managed to make a grid of squares with randomly generated color.

I decided to make each squares color increase and decrease in intensity but the result is only a small corner of the grid being drawn, and the color doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

[Online code here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/rP8bF/) and [paste bin here](http://pastebin.com/zh2Y6AdZ).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function square(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sizex = 10;
    this.sizey = 10;
    this.Colo = Colo;

    function Colo() {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1);
        var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 1) + 1);
        var run = true;
        var rup, gup, bup = true;
        while (run) {

            if (rup) {
                if (r == 255) {
                    rup = false;
                } else if (r == 0) {
                    rup = true;
                }

                r += 1;
                r.toString();

            } else if (!gup) {
                r -= 1;
                r.toString();
            }

            if (gup) {
                if (g == 255) {
                    gup = false;
                } else if (g == 0) {
                    gup = true;
                }
                g += 1;
                g.toString();

            } else if (!gup) {
                g -= 1;
                g.toString();
            }

            if (bup = true) {
                if (b == 255) {
                    bup = false;
                } else if (b == 0) {
                    bup = true;
                }

                b += 1;
                b.toString();

            } else if (!gup) {
                b -= 1;
                b.toString();
            }

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var col = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";

            return col;
            window.onfocus = function () {
                rup = true;
            };
            window.onblur = function () {
                isActive = false;
            };
            console.log("Ran loop.")
        }
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = Colo();
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.sizex, this.sizey);
}

var squares = new Array();
var p = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 72; j++) {
        p = i + j;
        squares[p] = new square(i * 10, j * 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `square()` constructor does this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = Colo();
ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.sizex, this.sizey);
```

... where `Colo()`, among other things, does this:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

So, you are clearing then entire canvas before painting each rectangle.